# TS2351: This expression is not constructable when I do a simple Vue import

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Novel TS + vue error here.

There are a few guys asking similar questions on StackOverflow over the past 2 months. No answers there.

Here is my error:

```
src/bus/myEventBus.ts:11:31
TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import("C:/Users/Roland/2021one-coding-projects/Vue2021/yawn/hyrule-jobs/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' has no construct signatures.
     9 | // console.log("shdafhkasfksd", typeof x, x)
    10 |
  > 11 | export const myEventBus = new Vue(); // fixme: What is this? new Vue is totally correct.
```

Here is the charming source of the issue:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export enum MyEventBusEvents {
    MyTestEvent = 'my_test_event', 
    AddJob = "add_a_job",
}

export const myEventBus = new Vue();
```

Its like, ok well, maybe I can specify something different by switching to `import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component'` and that will work. But then I get `TS2339: Property '$on' does not exist on type 'Vue<unknown, {}, {}>'.` which is not what I want. I want to use $on later to make an event bus.

```
// where the $on error is from
import { myEventBus, MyEventBusEvents } from "../bus/myEventBus";
// ... snip ...
created() {
        myEventBus.$on(
            MyEventBusEvents.AddJob,
            (title: string, loc: string, salary: number, ft: boolean) =>
                this.addJob(title, loc, salary, ft)
        );
    },
```

The expectation is that `new Vue()` sets up a new Vue instance so I can use it to send events back and forth using `$emit` and `$on`. [This tutorial](https://benbrougher.tech/vue-event-bus-tutorial/) claims everything works fine using the code I copied from it. Apparently not.

[Seems like it has potential but if the potential is real I'm doing it wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189533/how-can-i-solve-error-this-expression-is-not-constructable). The answer is marked as correct but I don't know what good it does me, which is different from it necessarily being useless.

[heres someone with similar issue in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071919/angular-typescript-this-expression-is-not-constructable-type-movedataclass). Bad answer for me. Look:

```
ERROR in src/bus/myEventBus.ts:1:10
TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'Vue'.
  > 1 | import { Vue } from 'vue'; // therefore adding { } does not help
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to set up EventBus in Vue3. Refer to this guide in order to do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019074/1773246